# Why isn't this jar packaging valid for Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, executable-jar

I am trying to understand the packaging of Spring Boot into "fat" jars. From what I know "fat" jars have their own special classes that load up the main class when the jar is running and also sets the classpath accordingly.

What I cannot understand is why when I use Eclipse to extract all my dependencies into a folder structure in the jar, the jar no longer runs as a correct Spring Boot application.

To repeat what I have done here just take a simple Spring Boot app and from Eclipse select the following-:

Export --> Runnable Jar --> Select Main Class --> Extract required libraries into jar.

Just run the jar from the command line as you would any jar. Spring Boot initially starts up but fails with the following message-:

> 2017-05-02 22:06:40.484  WARN 3468 --- [           main]
>   ationConfigEmbeddedWebA pplicationContext : Exception encountered
>   during context initialization - cancel ling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreExcep tion:
>   Failed to process import candidates for configuration class
>   [com.main.Test Main]; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **No auto configuration classes
>   found in META-INF/spring.factories. If you are using a custom packa
>   ging, make sure that file is correct.**

Can I somehow edit the spring.factories file to include my classses ?

I just trying to understand how Spring actually packages the files through its Maven plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that because it's a Spring Boot application, you need to use their plugin for building. It is because, spring Boot has its own jar loading mechanism for that (the BOOT-INF introduction in Spring Boot 1.4).

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

From documentation:

> The Spring Boot Maven Plugin provides Spring Boot support in Maven, allowing you to package executable jar or war archives and run an application “in-place”.

Link to documetantion [(Appendix E)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#executable-jar)
Something about [`spring.factories`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html) and locating auto-configuration candidates - [Auto-configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html)

Comment: Can I somehow replicate it ? Can I add my classes to spring.factories file and somehow have it run ? Is the spring boot class loading mechanism documented somewhere ?

Comment: I added link to Spring boot documentation